# Display "Loading..." image/message after Button_Click, while Page_Load / GridView update

Tags: loading

I now want to make some interface improvement for ASP.NET project. Example:

Show a Loading message with loading image GIF when Page_Load(), after Button_Click, while GridView update,...

I use loading element (HTML/CSS + jQuery) here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548385/how-to-show-loading-page-indicator-in-asp-net)

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender)
{
//code to show up element...
//code do something: check db connection, check cookie, check session,...
//code to hide loading element...
}
```

My problem is I never use AjaxToolkit before so I don't know how to use UpdatePanel, UpdateProcess to show up the loading element above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good example here:

[ajax "loading" icon with UpdatePanel postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813590/ajax-loading-icon-with-updatepanel-postbacks)

Just insert the loading element between `<ProgressTemplate> ... </ProgressTemplate>`

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: It works perfect on Button_Click() event. How I call it on Page_Load() event ?